# Are zookeeper nodes in Amazon MSK in different availability zones?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/msk/latest/developerguide/what-is-msk.html

Reading this documentation I do not clearly see whether zookeeper nodes are within the same subnet and therefore in the same availability zone. I assume that for high availability they are in different availability zones. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 or 3 AZs for you MSK clusters. You can deploy 1 or more nodes per AZ and by design they will be spread on the AZs you define.